# Сбой кодировки Tomcat

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Есть простой сайт. Одна из страниц html содержит кириллицу. Если открывать html файл браузером напрямую, то всё отображается корректно. Если собрать проект в war файл и захостить с помощью tomcat, то кириллица заменяется на вопросы и местами кашу. Использую java, spring mvc, maven, tomcat 9 версии. Конфигурация java кодом, а не с помощью web.xml. Текст на странице статический. Пробовал с помощью meta и filter явно указать кодировку - не помогло. Пробовал изменять server.xml в tomcat, тоже не помогло. 
Вырезка из pom.xml:

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    ...
  </properties>
```

Server.xml без комментариев:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
               
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Html файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
    <title>First</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Тут текст кириллицей.</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Класс фильтра:

```
package spring.config;

import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CharsetFilter implements Filter {

    private String encoding;

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
        if (encoding == null)
            encoding = "UTF-8";
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        next.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте кодировку на уровне ОС на которой стоит ваш Tomcat

Comment: всё нормально с кодировкой. дополнительно залил на хостинг. там тоже tomcat и та же проблема в итоге.

Comment: * имел ввиду всё нормально с кодировкой Windows. А с кодировкой, на которую заменяет tomcat, действительно проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорре всего, не актуально, но у меня было что-то похожее, я в силу того, что очень мало в этом варюсь потратил на решение три дня, что я только не делал ничего не помогало. помогло тольк измение **WebMvcConfigurer** .
Все, что я изменял в процессе поиска решения:

- добавление различных фильтров,
- в файлах tomcat менял настройки filter, connector,filter-mapping,
- создавал классы фильтров и ссылался на них отовсюду воббще - все это я удалил, у меня работает только благодаря вот этому решению:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.isis")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public Config(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
         viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[]{".html", ".xhtml"});
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setForceContentType(true);
        resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);

    }
}
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет не потратить на это три дня.[Решил благодаря этой статье](https://quares.ru/?id=49812)